# Spring security @PostAuthorize anotation don't work fine sometimes

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I'm using Spring [**Security 4.1.0**](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) for security of my java web application. I use `@PostAuthorize` annotation for `get` method as follow:

**Interface**:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('get')")
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'read')")
MyEntity get(Serializable id);
```

And `get` implemntation method is as follow:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public MyEntity get(Serializable id)
{
   MyEntity record = dao.get(id);
   System.out.println(record.getId() + " : " + record.getName());
   return record;
}
```

In `web.xml` I set sessionConfig as follow:

```
<session-config>
     <session-timeout> 10 </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

User login to application and call `get` method. User don't send a request to server in 3 minutes later. He send another request to cal `get` method. response is `403 Access Denied`, After this User send another same request Immediately, But response is **`200 OK`**. See this Requests:
**`403`** Response:
[image]

And `200` Response:
[image]

Tomcat console logs in 2 case as follow:

```
538 : MyEntity 2
```

**Whats the problem**?

**Is it a `spring security` bug**?

Comment: shouldn't `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('get')")` fail without a session?

Comment: All requests send after user login, then `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('get')")` is not the problem.

Comment: @zapl there's a JSESSIONID there present and it is the same in both requests

Comment: yes, but with a timeout of 10 seconds and 3 minutes of inactivity, shouldn't the server treat that session as invalid, therefore no longer granting you anything? session id is sent client side. Edit: oops, 10 minutes. I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: timeout is not 10 seconds, it is 10 minutes.

Comment: Do you have spring security settings elsewhere defined? I had a similar problem where `@PreAuthorize` didn't work. In my configuration i had to annotate `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` so `@PreAuthorize` would work.

Comment: I defined `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" >`